# html - multiple tables vs 1 table and multiple tr - performance

Tags: html, css, ajax

I was wondering if there's a performance difference between having multiple tables vs having a single table with multiple `<tr>`, with both cases having the same number of `<td>`.

Right now, I'm using multiple tables for the reason of ajax, but when I have 100 results up, the browser is a bit sluggish. Most of the content is just text and a few buttons, but one of the columns is an iframe.

Comment: Rendering a <TABLE> DOM element need more resource than adding new tags to the existing DOM. As i think.

Comment: From your description it's not even clear that you need tables at all.

Comment: tables are just for consistent look